# How to implement AtomicU32, an atomic 32-bit integer type?

Tags: rust, atomic

The module [std::sync::atomic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/atomic/index.html) doesn't contain fixed size integral atomic types. In my 64-bit application, I need to create a vector of atomic 32-bit integers. Is there a workaround? Can I implement something like an AtomicU32 (or AtomicI32) myself, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::intrinsics`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/intrinsics/index.html) module contains intrinsic atomic functions that are generic. This means you can basically copy-paste [the implementation for `AtomicUsize` and/or `AtomicIsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/core/sync/atomic.rs.html) and change the wrapped type from `usize`/`isize` to `u32`/`i32`.

However, these intrinsics are unstable, so you need to use a nightly Rust compiler in order to make this work. If that's not acceptable to you, consider [submitting an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs) to get such types added to the standard library. If using a nightly Rust compiler is OK for you, then it might be interesting to [publish a crate](https://crates.io/) that contains these types. This will have the advantage of gathering statistics on how useful such types are. (Dependents will still need to use a nightly compiler though, so the effect might be somewhat underestimated.)

Comment: "The atomic intrinsics provide common atomic operations on machine words, with multiple possible memory orderings." this has the same downside as my solution

Comment: The generic intrinsic functions accept any integer type (otherwise LLVM will complain about invalid IR). Look at the IR generated here, for example: http://is.gd/I3Loxb.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can implement other sizes than pointer-sized integers. [AtomicBool is actually padded in Rust to pointer size](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cff04117064ddee95f425c49f22c8aa5a3a665d4/src/libcore/sync/atomic.rs#L86).

LLVM [states](http://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html) that

> Common architectures have some way of representing at least a pointer-sized lock-free cmpxchg; such an operation can be used to implement all the other atomic operations which can be represented in IR up to that size.

Therefor you will never save space with smaller integers.

On the other hand, if you just want nice access and don't care about the memory, you can implement wrappers:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicIsize, Ordering};

struct AtomicI32(AtomicIsize);
impl AtomicI32 {
    fn new(v: i32) -> AtomicI32 {
        AtomicI32(AtomicIsize::new(v as isize))
    }
    fn load(&self, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.load(order) as i32
    }
    fn store(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) {
        self.0.store(val as isize, order)
    }
    fn swap(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.swap(val as isize, order) as i32
    }
    fn compare_and_swap(&self, current: i32, new: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.compare_and_swap(current as isize, new as isize, order) as i32
    }
    fn fetch_add(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.fetch_add(val as isize, order) as i32
    }
    fn fetch_sub(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.fetch_sub(val as isize, order) as i32
    }
    fn fetch_and(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.fetch_and(val as isize, order) as i32
    }
    fn fetch_or(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.fetch_or(val as isize, order) as i32
    }
    fn fetch_xor(&self, val: i32, order: Ordering) -> i32 {
        self.0.fetch_xor(val as isize, order) as i32
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, for my use case, doubling the RAM consumption is not an option.

Comment: since your use-case is a vector of 32bit atomics on a 64bit machine, you could create a wrapper around a `Vec` that internally has half the number of items and always accesses the lower or higher part of the 64bit word, depending on whether the index is even or odd. Are you sure you need a `Vec` of atomics and not simply a `Mutex<Vec<i32>>`?